# Is there any working example for pgr_trsp ?

Tags: pgrouting

I'm trying to use pgrouting pgr_trsp function but result is useless. Exactly same code with pgr_dijkstra working OK and find shortest path between start and stop but with pgr_trsp it is look like random jumps around map.

I'm using this code

`SELECT a.seq, a.id1 AS node, a.id2 AS to, a.cost, cr_2po_4pgr.osm_name, 
ST_AsText(ST_GeomFromEWKB(decode(cr_2po_4pgr.the_geom,'hex'))) as geodata FROM pgr_dijkstra ('SELECT gid as id, source, target, cost FROM cr_2po_4pgr', $start,$end,false, false) as a left join cr_2po_4pgr on a.id2 = cr_2po_4pgr.gid`

Based on documentation trsp should be almost same as dijkstra but i can use turn restriction code. But even basic is not working. What i'm doing wrong ?

Comment: GREAT EXAMPLE! That´s what we need! Is it necessary to create the restriction table? Is it possible to have the restrictions in the same table?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 7):

You're probably confusing node ids with edges ids (the algorithm works with edges rather than nodes).

Anyway, I think the documentation is not really good at that example. Try this instead:

Create the restriction table this way:

```
CREATE TABLE restrictions (
        rid serial,
        to_cost double precision,
        target_id integer,
        via_path text
    );

INSERT INTO restrictions VALUES (1, 1000, 11, '8,4,1');
```

You have the sample network [here](http://docs.pgrouting.org/2.0/en/doc/src/developer/sampledata.html#sampledata). So, that restriction says: *if you come along edges 1 - 4 - 8, then you can pass trough edge 11 only with a cost of 1000*.

That implies that, for example, if you followed the nodes 1 - 2 - 5 - 6, then going to node 11 will cost 1000 (I want to avoid that turn).

Now, try this query (no turn restrictions)

```
SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost
FROM pgr_trsp(
        'SELECT id, source, target, cost FROM edge_table',
        1, 11, false, false
);
```

You will get the node path **1 - 2 - 5 - 6 - 11**.

If you apply the turn restriction's table, the step from node 6 to node 11 will be really expensive. So, the algorithm will avoid it. Let's try it

```
SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost
FROM pgr_trsp(
        'SELECT id, source, target, cost FROM edge_table',
        1, 11, false, false,
        'SELECT to_cost, target_id, via_path FROM restrictions'
);
```

And the node path will be **1 - 2 - 5 - 10 - 11**